# Troubles with provisioning profiles in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I face some issue when I'm connected the iPhone with the Xcode :

1. > No profiles for 'com.robcanton.FirebaseApp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.robcanton.FirebaseApp'. (in target 'FirebaseApp')
2. > Failed to create provisioning profile. The app ID "com.robcanton.FirebaseApp" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again. (in target 'FirebaseApp')

Comment: Please illustrate your specific problem you're having in a [MCVE] - otherwise it will be quite difficult for us to help. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: That bundleId has already been registered by another development team.  Since your name isn't Rob Canton, I presume you are working with an example or tutorial project.  You need to change the bundle id to something unique.